# Retrieve another user UID using the a child node data

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic5

I am creating a referral code function for my ionic web-app. Currently when a referral code is being submitted and it exists in the firebase real time database, 50 points will be added to current user account. However I am trying to also add points to the other user whose referral code is being used.

So far I am trying to call the UID of the other user then i will call that UID and create the update function. But I am not able to get the UID, is there a way I can do this? I have added my firebase structure and the code I have tried. [image: this is my database structure]

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('users/').startAt(this.checking.referralCode).endAt(this.checking.referralCode);
ref.once("child_added", function(snapp) {
    console.log(snapp.key); 
});
```

UPDATE:
I have tried this code, however it brings out all of the UID, is there a way I can specify which UID I want using the data from referral code?

```
 var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");

ref.orderByKey().endAt("referralCode").on("child_added", function(snapp) {
  var key = snapp.key;
  console.log(key)
```

Thank you !

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sound like you're trying to order/filter on the `referralCode` child value, which you can do with:

```
var query = ref.orderByChild("referralCode").equalTo("56483579").limitToFirst(1);
query.once("child_added").then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key); // "jHl9Srh..."
})
```

---

If there may be multiple child nodes with the same value, you'd do:

```
var query = ref.orderByChild("referralCode").equalTo("56483579");
query.once("value").then(function(results) {
  results.forEach(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key); // "jHl9Srh..."
  })
})
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the code but I did not receive any output from the console.log(). Also for the equalTo('564835797'), is there a way I can put whatever has been input by the user? 

For a example in my html page, I have an input where the user will write the referral code. Is it possible if the equalTo is read to that input?

Comment: You can put whatever you want in the `equalTo` call, as long as its value is what you want to compare to. I hard-coded the value in my answer to make it clear what the eventual value of whatever you pass in needs to be. So if your `this.checking.referralCode` has the value `56483579`, passing that will work the same as in my answer.

Comment: Ah okay thank you, however nothing happens when I write that code in

Comment: "nothing happens" is not very easy to help with. I'm pretty comfortable with this API, but may of course have missed something. If you can't get what I answered to work, it might be useful if you set up a reproduction of where you are stuck in a site like jsbin, so that I can have a look there.

Comment: Hello I managed to update it, I needed to change the `this.checking.referralCode` to an integer

Thank you for your help!